# Using variable for x, y coordinates in GRect? (Java newbie)

Tags: java

I'm just learning Java, and I am working with a GRect object.  I'm trying to assign the x and y coordinates to an int, but not having luck.  I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Specifically, I'm looking at the getHeight():

Basically, I've got

```
add(new GRect(moveRight,getHeight(), BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT));
```

That is working fine, but I assigned getHeight to an int, and then it doesn't work:

```
int displayHeight = getHeight();    

add(new GRect(moveRight,displayHeight,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT));
```

Any ideas?

To clarify-from what I have gathered from these online classes, getHeight() will return the height of the graphics window if it isn't assigned to a class.

With the above, I'm trying to get the GRect to start at the bottom of the graphics window...as I said, when having the first example above, the rectangles move correctly, in the second example, they remain at the top of the display.

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: Well what does getHeight() return? GRect takes a double, is getHeight() returning a double?

Comment: as far as I know getHeight() without a class attached gives you the height of the whole window...  GRect takes a double or int, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was not properly declaring the variable within the method.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that getHeight() is returning a double that has a value <1.0, if it does you may be losing your information and being stuck with a 0.
Try changing int into double and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

what's the return type of getHeight()?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without a lot of context. Obviously my earlier guess was not good (not a compilation error). It seems `getHeight()` returns an int.

Do you know if `x=0, y=0` point is the top left corner or the bottom left corner? I think it's possible you need to call:

```
int y = getHeight() - BRICK_HEIGHT;
add(new GRect(moveRight,y,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT));
```

That does not explain why the first instance works, though...

Comment: hi.  It compiles.  But the top example the rectangles move down (they are understanding the call of getHeight(),) but the second example, they are not receiving that call.